# TypeORM @JoinTable() how to specify custom join columns?

Tags: typeorm

this is my sample data model

[image]

I have declared the following classes:

```js
@Entity({
  name: 'user'
})
export class User {
  @Column({ type: 'int4' })
  @PrimaryColumn()
  userid: number
    
  @Column({name: 'name', type: 'varchar', length: 30})
  name: string
    
  @Column({name: 'age', type: 'int2'})
  age: number
    
  @ManyToMany(() => Department, (department)=> department.users)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'department_user'
  })
  departments: Department[]
}

@Entity({ name: 'department' })
export class Department {
    
  @Column({ type: 'int2' })
  @PrimaryColumn()
  departmentid: number
    
  @Column({type: 'varchar', length: 50})
  title: string
    
  @Column({type:'text'})
  notes: string
    
  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user)=> user.departments)
  @JoinTable({ name: 'department_user' })
  users: User[]  
}
```

whenever I run the app, it creates the **departmentDepartmentId** & **userUserId** columns and not utilize the columns in the corresponding join table. How can I tell typeorm to only use the predefined join column in  join table?

#### Update 2 (as mentioned by @suvantorw)

I recreated the join table with the statement below:

```
create table department_user(
departmentid integer not null, 
userid integer not null);

alter table department_user add constraint fk_dept_dept foreign key (departmentid) references department(departmentid);
alter table department_user add constraint fk_dept_user foreign key (userid) references "user"(userid);
alter table department_user add constraint pk_dept_user primary key (departmentid, userid);
```

and modified the entities like this:

**user**

```js
  @ManyToMany(() => Department, (department)=> department.users)
  @JoinTable({ 
    name: 'department_user',
    joinColumn: { name: 'userid' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'departmentid' }
  })
  departments: Department[]
}
```

**department**

```js
  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user)=> user.departments)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'department_user',
    joinColumn: { name: 'departmentid' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { referencedColumnName: 'userid' }
  })
  users: User[]  
}
```

it does run without errors but when it runs the table structure is modified to this
[image: modified table structure]

As you can see, ,y foreign key constraints are gone and new ones are created. Any clue what I'm doing wrong here?

#### Update 3

Finally I modified the classes as below and now the TypeORM accepts the relationships and does not create its own. it was a very painful experience to solve this and documentation about this decorator doesn't say much either.

**user**

```js
  @ManyToMany(() => Department, (department)=> department.users)
  @JoinTable({ 
    name: 'department_user',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'userid',
      foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_dept_user'
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      referencedColumnName: 'departmentid',
      name: 'departmentid',
      foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_dept_dept'
    }
  })
  departments: Department[]
}
```

**department**

```js
@ManyToMany(() => User, (user)=> user.departments)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'department_user',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'departmentid',
      foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_dept_dept'
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      referencedColumnName: 'userid',
      name: 'userid',
      foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_dept_user'
    }
  })
  users: User[]  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the join column name and inverse join column name. Something like this should work for you:

```
@ManyToMany(() => Department, (department)=> department.users)
@JoinTable({ 
    name: 'department_user',
    joinColumn: { name: 'userid' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'departmentid' }
})
departments: Department[]
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the changes as you suggested.  Can you please have a look?

Comment: Update 2 looks good. I was actually unaware of the ability to set foreignKeyConstraintName in join relationships from your update 3 so thanks for posting that.